# Log Analytics KQL with Time Range does not work from App Insights using "workspace"

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a `Log Analytics` `KQL` as below for `Custom Table` with `Time Range`; it works fine in `Log Analytics`.

You can notice the **Time range = Set in query** automatically.

[image: Log Analytics KQL]

---

But when I run the same `KQL` from `App Insights` using `workspace`, it doesn't take `TimeGenerated` into to account and fetches data for **Time range** set in `App Insights` and returns wrong resultset!

You can notice the **Time range = Last 30 minutes** in-spite I have given `TimeGenerated > ago(365d)`!

[image: App Insights]

> I have noticed same issue with `App Insights` KQL running in `Log Analytics` using `app()` function!

Not sure what is wrong or is it a restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is that in `application insights`, it uses the `timestamp` column to represent the logged time. But in `Log analytics`, it uses the `TimeGenerated` column to represent the logged time.

So when in Application insights, you use workspace("log-analytics") and `TimeGenerated > ago(10d)`, the application insights does not recognize `TimeGenerated`.

A screenshot as below:

[image]

In this situation, the solution is that, you should rename `TimeGenerated` to `timestamp` which can be recognized by application insights. The sample query like below:

[image]